# id from url to php variable

Tags: php, mysql

I'm facing the next problem:
i have a unique id per article, but i don't know how to ask it in the next page in my while loop into SELECT * FROM WHERE ask_id = x. now the id of href (the link) should be added to the x. actually i just want to turn the id in the search bar into the variable x

```
<?php
$statement = $pdo2->prepare("SELECT * FROM fragen ORDER BY fragen_date DESC");
$result = $statement->execute();
while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
        echo '<a class="kein" href="forum_forum.php?id='.$row['fragen_id'].'"><div class="forum"><div class="forum_Titel">' ,"Titel:  ".$row['fragen_title'].'</div>',
        "<br><br>",'<div class="forum_Subt  itel">', "Subtitel:  " .$row['fragen_subtitle'].'</div>',
        "<br><br>",'<div class="forum_Content">',"Text:  ".$row['fragen_content'].'</div>',
        "br><br>",'<div>'.$row['fragen_id'].'</div>',
        "<br><br>",'<div class="forum_Upload-date">',"Upload-Datum:  ".$row['fragen_date'].'</div>',
        '</div></a>';
    //the variable $chosen_one should get the value of the id   

    }               
?>
```

as you can see, it generates the id for the url correctly

```
<?php
$statement = $pdo2->prepare("SELECT * FROM fragen WHERE ");
$result = $statement->execute();
while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
        echo '<div class="forum"><div class="forum_Titel">' ,"Titel:  ".$row['fragen_title'].'</div>',
        "<br><br>",'<div class="forum_Subitel">', "Subtitel:  " .$row['fragen_subtitle'].'</div>',
        "<br><br>",'<div class="forum_Content">',"Text:  ".$row['fragen_content'].'</div>',
        "<br><br>",'<div class="forum_Bild"><img class="pic" alt="Ein Bild" title="Eine Pflanzen" src="'.$row['fragen_picture'].'">',
        "<br><br>","Bildlink:  ".$row['fragen_picture'].'</div>',
        "<br><br>",'<div class="forum_Upload-date">',"Upload-Datum:  ".$row['fragen_date'].'</div>',
        '</div>';

}
?>
```

now it should ask at the top of the document in the part of SELECT *FROM WHERE fragen_id = id of the url

[image: i mean this id]

Comment: please ve VERY careful when taking info from the url straight to your DB

Comment: ah no i am only comparing the db with the url id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters on the querystring are delivered to PHP in the `$_GET` array.

So `forum_forum.php` just needs to pick that up and bind it to the placeholder in the prepared statement

```
<?php

$statement = $pdo2->prepare("SELECT * FROM fragen WHERE fragen_id = :id");
// here we put a value into the parameter
$result = $statement->execute([':id' => (int)$_GET['id']]);

while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<div class="forum"><div class="forum_Titel">' ,"Titel:  ".$row['fragen_title'].'</div>',
        "<br><br>",'<div class="forum_Subitel">', "Subtitel:  " .$row['fragen_subtitle'].'</div>',
        "<br><br>",'<div class="forum_Content">',"Text:  ".$row['fragen_content'].'</div>',
        "<br><br>",'<div class="forum_Bild"><img class="pic" alt="Ein Bild" title="Eine Pflanzen" src="'.$row['fragen_picture'].'">',
        "<br><br>","Bildlink:  ".$row['fragen_picture'].'</div>',
        "<br><br>",'<div class="forum_Upload-date">',"Upload-Datum:  ".$row['fragen_date'].'</div>',
        '</div>';

}
?>
```